# Pandas : How to concatenate or merge the groups using groupby function and populate single table or dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df =  name  description curve   tenor   rates
       IND     3M       ZAR_3M   0.25   6.808000088
       IND     2Y       ZAR_3M    2     6.483012199
       IND     3Y       ZAR_3M    3     6.565002918
       IND    4Y        ZAR_3M    4      6.694129944
       IND    5Y        ZAR_3M    5      6.83951807
       IND    3M        CAD_OIS   0.25   1.738620043
       BHU    6M        CAD_OIS   0.5   1.718042016
       IND    9M        CAD_OIS   0.75  1.697247028
       IND    1Y        CAD_OIS    1    1.67719996
       IND   18M        CAD_OIS   1.5   1.631257057
       IND    2Y        CAD_3M    2     1.906309009
       IND    3y        CAD_3M    3     1.855569959
       IND    4Y        CAD_3M    4     1.830132961
       BHU    5Y        CAD_3M    5     1.817605019
       BHU    6y        CAD_3M    6     1.814880013
       IND    7Y        CAD_3M    7     1.821526051
       BHU   TND        CZK_Curve 0.01  0.02
       BHU   1WK        CZK_Curve 0.03  0.0203
       BHU   1M         CZK_Curve 0.09  0.021
       BHU   2M         CZK_Curve 0.18  0.0212
       BHU   3M         CZK_Curve 0.26  0.0214
       BHU   6M         CZK_Curve 0.51  0.0212
       BHU   9M         CZK_Curve 0.76  0.02045
       BHU  12M         CZK_Curve 1.01  0.01985
       BHU  2Y          CZK_Curve 2.01  0.020033333
       BHU  3Y          CZK_Curve 3.02  0.018816667
       BHU  4Y          CZK_Curve 4.02  0.017666667
       BHU  5Y          CZK_Curve 5.02  0.016616667
       BHU  6Y          CZK_Curve 6.02  0.015766667
       BHU  7Y          CZK_Curve 7.02  0.015216667
       BHU  8Y          CZK_Curve 8.02  0.014616667
       BHU  9Y          CZK_Curve 9.02  0.014358333
```

Above is my dataframe(df) having 5 variables. I would like to populate the table based on 'curve' and rename the rates as curve name. Following is my expected output. I tried using groupby function to generate groups and concatenate side by side based on 'tenor'. But my code seems incomplete. Please suggest to how to produce the below output.

```
df_tenor = df_tenor[['Tenor']].drop_duplicates()
df_tenor = df_tenor.sort_values(by=['tenor'])
gb = df.groupby('curve')
df.rename(columns={'rates': str([df.curve.unique() for g in gb])}, inplace=True)
df_final= pd.concat([g[1].merge(df_tenor, how='outer', on='Tenor') for g in gb], axis=1)
df_final.to_csv('testconcat.csv', index = False)
```

[image]

Comment: this is a pivot problem: `df.set_index(['name','description','tenor','curve'])['rates'].unstack()` should do, drop extra levels if you want

Comment: or try crosstab `pd.crosstab(df.tenor,df.curve,df.rates,aggfunc=lambda x : x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ``pandas.pivot_table()```

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='tenor', values='rates', columns='curve')
```

Output

```
curve    CAD_3M   CAD_OIS  CZK_Curve    ZAR_3M
tenor
0.01        NaN       NaN   0.020000       NaN
0.03        NaN       NaN   0.020300       NaN
0.09        NaN       NaN   0.021000       NaN
0.18        NaN       NaN   0.021200       NaN
0.25        NaN  1.738620        NaN  6.808000
0.26        NaN       NaN   0.021400       NaN
0.50        NaN  1.718042        NaN       NaN
0.51        NaN       NaN   0.021200       NaN
0.75        NaN  1.697247        NaN       NaN
0.76        NaN       NaN   0.020450       NaN
1.00        NaN  1.677200        NaN       NaN
1.01        NaN       NaN   0.019850       NaN
1.50        NaN  1.631257        NaN       NaN
2.00   1.906309       NaN        NaN  6.483012
2.01        NaN       NaN   0.020033       NaN
3.00   1.855570       NaN        NaN  6.565003
3.02        NaN       NaN   0.018817       NaN
4.00   1.830133       NaN        NaN  6.694130
4.02        NaN       NaN   0.017667       NaN
5.00   1.817605       NaN        NaN  6.839518
5.02        NaN       NaN   0.016617       NaN
6.00   1.814880       NaN        NaN       NaN
6.02        NaN       NaN   0.015767       NaN
7.00   1.821526       NaN        NaN       NaN
7.02        NaN       NaN   0.015217       NaN
8.02        NaN       NaN   0.014617       NaN
9.02        NaN       NaN   0.014358       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. Its working. I wrongly saved in csv. This one is the great approach.